# Adding a property to an Entity Framework Entity from another table

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I'm just starting out with the Entity Framework and ADO.NET Data Services and I've run into an issue that I can't seem to figure out.  I have two tables, one that has user information and the other that has a created by field.  Within the database, there isn't a foreign key between these tables.  The user table contains an arbitrary Id, a username, and a display name.  The created by field contains the user's username.  In my entity I would like to have the user's display name since this is what I need to display and expose over the ADO.NET Data Service?  I'm aware that I could restructure the database, but I was hoping that I could do the join using the username as I would in a SQL statement.

Thanks in advance,

-Damien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a view using a join of both tables, and then use this object to display the user's name.

There's some info on mapping custom queries [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc982038.aspx).

Comment: I ended up adding a defining query based on the link you provided and then merged the property into the item.